# What tool can generate a blank SRT file with candidate scene changes

Tags: detection, scene, subtitle, srt

I'd like to add subtitles to a video file for which no SRT file exists. Is there any tool that'll automatically scan the audio track of a Video and create a blank SRT file that contains only the time stamps?

I tried VisualSubSync, but the built-in **Scan for Scene changes** tool apparently only works with existing SRT files.

Basically, I'm looking for an Open Source offline equivalent of [GoSubtitle](http://gosubtitle.com) (without the speech recognition feature).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. I would recommend to try on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It is a little hard for offline powerful software like that because you need the power of machine learning that the online solutions house.

This can sound a little bold but have you encountered YouTube's automatic captioning service? It has a limited language support but it does an excellent job and for free :) [References](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6373554?hl=en)

(I'm doing a small search now and will update with all alternatives)

Comment: i haven't forgotten still  testing something from my side and will update